# how read unstructured xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to read XML which is unstructured. number of sub elemnet may be increase or decrease. what is the best way to read this type of XML in C#. Sample XML is bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entities>
    <entity>
        <type>Organization</type>
        <relevance>0.918192</relevance>
        <sentiment>
            <type>neutral</type>
        </sentiment>
        <count>1</count>
        <text>Wheelers Hill Secondary College Deb Ball</text>
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <type>Organization</type>
        <relevance>0.621802</relevance>
        <sentiment>
            <type>positive</type>
            <score>0.789945</score>
        </sentiment>
        <count>1</count>
        <text>Greensborough College</text>
        <disambiguated>
            <name>Greensborough College</name>
            <subType>School</subType>
            <website>http://www.greensc.vic.edu.au/</website>
            <dbpedia>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Greensborough_College
            </dbpedia>
            <freebase>http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.0bp2jy</freebase>
        </disambiguated>
    </entity>
</entities>
```

Comment: I'd suggest doing some research on Linq to XML (XDocument).

Comment: I did search but these all ways to read a structured XML file which have number of sub elements constant. I want to read XML in which number of attributes are not constant

Comment: What is your scenario? Do you want to read some attributes / elements, all of them, how do you want to use the read data?

Comment: what does best way mean? are you looking at performance?

Comment: I want to read all XML elements.

Comment: best way which read all elements as shown variation in number of element in the XML

Comment: Just instantiate an XmlDocument object, do a Load(fileName) on the XML file, and then you can traverse the structure by using XPath and/or following the Child and Parent links.

Comment: Another approach is to write your classes and map them to this xml and then do a deserialization of this XML. This will give you a full object model of your xml, which you can modify and operate with ease

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy I did not understand how do code which you are saying. can you give me code example? thanks

Comment: XmlDocument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615339/reading-xml-file-and-accessing-optional-nodes. LINQ to XML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278215/linq-to-xml-optional-element-query; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/05/14/working-with-optional-elements-and-attributes-in-linq-to-xml-queries.aspx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to read the XML in C# is to use LINQ. You can use the below code to query XML and get the required elements.

First Create an extension method to check whether an element exists and return its values

```
public static string CheckAndGetElementValue(this XElement parent, string elementName, string defaultValue = null) 
{
    var el = parent.Element(elementName);
    if(el != null)
    {
         return el.Value;
    }
    else
    {
         return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

than use the extension method while fetching value of the element:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("filename");
var listitems = (from el in xDoc.Descendants("entities")
                where el.Element("entity").CheckAndGetElementValue("type") == "Organization"
                select el);
```